# How to make the uploaded file available for use after saving it with GetRandomFileName according to the FileHelpers example?

Tags: asp.net-core

In the [documentation sample code](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/main/aspnetcore/mvc/models/file-uploads/samples/3.x/SampleApp/Utilities/FileHelpers.cs) for how to deal with user uploaded files, they save it as a trusted filename for filestorage via GetRandomFileName, and a trusted filename for HTML display.

In the comments it says: "*In most production scenarios, an anti-virus/anti-malware scanner API is used on the file before making the file available for download or for use by other systems.*"

Is that going to be before it is saved with a random filename or after? Because that is the point of saving it as a random filename, so that it doesn't get executed? And when the scanning is done, how is the file going to be made available? I guess the file just has to be renamed if it passes the scan or else deleted? If so, what is the proper way to get the original file extenstion? And do you know of any good scanners that are gratis that are popular to use?

I try to learn web development. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

The renaming of the file here has nothing to do with the anti-virus protection. The files don't tend to execute themselves whatever their name is. Same with the virus scan: it's not for the server protection, it's for the users protection. If your server executes the binary it gets from the client, it's a security breach regardless of whether it's a virus or not.

The renaming here is probably done just to be able to store the duplicates. That being said, in the production scenarios you'll probably never store the incoming files as physical files on the FS. They usually go to the DB as blobs, so the name is not an issue.

This is just a sample app designed to teach how to work with binary streams and file controllers. Don't expect too much from it in terms of applicability to the real solutions.

Comment: Yes, I try to follow OWASP recommendations, but I was unsure of how to rename the files to make them available after the scan? The renaming is done to prevent logical errors or exploits returning the results after a scan or even by rendering the filename in a template, or otherwise if there for example is no check to forbid double extenstions++, etc?

Comment: Or not how, but whether to rename the files afterwards - what is the method, or the traditional/secure way (can only edit the other comment for 5 min..) Now I can learn how to use Azure Blob or filestorage made by people who know what they are doing, but that is not my goal, I want to be the one who knows everything about it like they do - this is only for learning purposes.

Comment: I don't know how the example changes the files back, I didn't study it much. Maybe it doesn't. As for "standard" way of doing it, as I said, the "standard" is to put files in the DB as blobs, not as physical files. That's why there is no such problem as file renaming in the production cases.